# PHP: Retaining drop down fields in new page

Tags: php, forms, post

I have 1 page that displays a form with various dropdowns that are being populated dynamically.

**Snippit**

```
 <td valign="top">
                    <select name="status">
                        <option></option>

                        <?php
                            foreach($statuslst as $status){
                                echo '<option value=' . $status[0] . '>' . $status[1] . '</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

I have a 2nd page that also displays this form but also the results from the form. the first form is posting to the 2nd and the 2nd is posting to itself.

I want the items chosen in the first form to be selected when posted to the second form.

Can someone steer me in the right direction here?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken your form is GET type, you could do something like this on the **second** page:

```
<?php
  foreach($statuslst as $status){
    $var = '';
    if($_GET['status'] == $status['0']){$var = ' selected="selected"';}
    echo '<option value="' . $status[0] .'"'. $var .'>' . $status[1] . '</option>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't forget to validate and null-check your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forgot to check the variable exists using

```
isset($_GET['status'])
```

or

```
isset($_GET['status'])
```

depending on what you're using, as it's not ideal to check the variable without doing this first.

eg.  if (isset($_GET['status')) && $_GET['status'] == $status[0] for example

Comment: no problems, otherwise you may get a warning in your logs for checking an empty var

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      foreach($statuslst as $status){
          echo '<option value="'.$status[0].'"'.(in_array($status[0],$_POST['status']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'. $status[1].'</option>';
      }
 ?>
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the selected attribute to the option tags on the 2nd form. Take a look at [selected option](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: but how do I set which option is selected?